# Как расположить коллайдеры на границах перспективной камеры в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d-android

Мне нужно расположить коллайдеры на границах камеры, делаю мобильную игру поэтому нужно подгонять колайдеры под разные разрешения.
У меня есть объект который контролирует игрок, мне нужно чтобы он не мог выйти за границы камеры.[image: сцена]

Если еще проще, то сделать то что вот в этом видео https://youtu.be/vIFLEa2CIFc только в 3д

Comment: может проще камеру под сцену подогнать, а не сцену под камеру?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @aepot на самом деле нет - потому что у разных телефонов разное соотношение сторон же

Comment: Ну подход ровно тот же, что и на видео на которое ты ссылаешься. просто вместо 2д обьектов с 2д коллайдерами используешь 3д обьекты с 3д коллайдерами. Только размещай их внутри камеры если что.